# fluorescence signal measurments accross the line

Tags: macros, imagej

I wrote a small macro to detect the boundaries of the cells. I was wondering if it is possible to write a macro for ImageJ to automatically draw several lines within these boundaries and get plot profiles? alternatively, I can shrink boundaries to find the centre of the cells and then have a macro to draw lines of fixed size through the centre point both would do I think.

Best and thank you
Sev

Comment: Hi Sev,
I'm pretty sure that's possible. Could you provide the following:
1. Your macro for detecting the boundaries of the cells.
2. A link to a sample data set.
3. rough image of what you want the final output of the program to be?

I'll be able to help out after that.